# How to test if a SQL Server Geography column value is POINT(0 0)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, geography

The following code works, but it woefully slow:

```
select top 100 FooId
from dbo.Foos
where latitudelongitude.ToString() = 'POINT(0,0)'
order by FooId desc
```

Is there a better way to determine if a `GEOGRAPHY` value has the Lat/Long of `0,0` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flip yo test, yo. ;)

```
declare @g geography = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(0 0)', 4326);

select * 
from dbo.Foos 
where latitudelongitude.STEquals(@g) = 1
```

Put another way, the query that you originally wrote wasn't SARGable. The one that I wrote is.

Comment: Have you even tried that? Well, I did as my _first_ attempt. Failed: `Invalid operator for data type. Operator equals equal to, type equals geography.`. I then tried the suggestion in the OP. Next time, please test before suggesting answers.

Comment: No, you didn't try that as your first attempt. You tried something very similar, but it's not the same (because you can't have a geography instance without an SRID). But you're correct; I didn't test it first. I have now and have updated my answer accordingly. Next time, please check your tone for people that are trying to help you with a problem that you're having for free.

Comment: Ah! `STEquals` ... I've never used that before :) hmmm. i wonder what is more performant ....

Comment: Try it out, but I know that STEquals is supported by spatial indexes, so I'd put my money on that.

Comment: This is more performant :) Answer swapped. (UPDATE): yep. the spatial index helped - you're the winnah!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `.Lat` and `.Long` to achieve that. Something like this

```
SELECT TOP 100 FooId
FROM dbo.Foos
WHERE latitudelongitude.Lat = 0 AND latitudelongitude.Long = 0
ORDER BY FooId desc
```